# Why can't we see time?

Tags: spacetime, time, relativity

If we live not in 3 dimensional space but in 4 dimensional space time, then, why can't we "see" the fourth dimension? Shouldn't I see time like any other spatial dimension? Instead, I perceive it to be as flowing.

How is time fundamentally different from space in this sense?

Comment: You can't see space either. (If you think you can - what does it look like?) I think what you really want to know is why can any object move back and forth in space but not so with time?

Comment: When you observe an elongated object, you see how it extends in space. And when you read these words, don't you also see how their sequence extends in time?